# Apache POI to keep predefined macros after editing

Tags: java, excel, vba, apache-poi, xlsm

I have `XLSX` and `XLSM` files which contains some predefined macros. I try to use `Apache POI` to edit these files, but macros are removed automatically. I get a notification window when I try to open file after modification, that files are removed, because file is broken:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error066080_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Error in file (C:\_privat\completeReport.xlsm)</summary>
    <removedRecords>
        <removedRecord>/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml</removedRecord>
        <removedRecord>/xl/calcChain.xml</removedRecord>
    </removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

I use following code to handle fle, `Vars.XLS` contains path to a `XLSX/XLSM` file.

```
File file = new File(Vars.XLS);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(recordcount+4);
Cell cell;

cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(recordcount);

inputStream.close();
FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream(Vars.XLS);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: A `*.xlsx` file cannot contain macros, only `*.xlsm` can. And the recovery log shown has nothing to do with macro removing. A worksheet and the calculation chain was removed. And your code shown does simple things which thousands  of other `apache poi` users also are doing without problems. So your problems are not related to the code but probably to the used file where `Vars.XLS` points to. So no help possible without having that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update an excel sheet. In case of updation, you should not create row or cell, rather you have to read the cell. I provide below the brief code snippet, you can try.

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(some number);
Cell cell = row.getCell(some number);
cell.setCellValue(recordcount);
```

Comment: I don't get error message, but file size is smaller after modification than original one, but I added a few more lines.